# Workaround to ALLSELECTED(ALLEXCEPT (table ))?

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I am trying to build the measure:

```
CALCULATE([Revenue] ,
        
    DATESYTD(dateadd('Date'[Date],-1,Year),"5/31"),
       
    ALLSELECTED(ALLEXCEPT ( ClientType, ClientType[FiscalYear] ))                
        
        )
```

Unfortunately ALLSELECTED is not allowed nested with an ALLEXCEPT.

- I need the ALLSELECTED, so I can ignore the filter in the current query.
- I need the ALLEXCEPT, because I need to ignore a filter from outside on another column, but I do want to preserve the outside filter on FiscalYear!

ALLSELECTED(ALLEXCEPT (  ))   would solve this; but ALLSELECTED expects a table as argument.

Comment: does `ALLSELECTED(), ALLEXCEPT ( ClientType, ClientType[FiscalYear] )` give you the correct result? if not using KEEPFILTERS may be an option https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-keepfilters-in-dax/

Comment: It didnt work. I am also unable to get it with keepfilters

Comment: can you elaborate what's the use case exactly? What's the relationship between the fact table, ClientType and Date? Which filters are active on which columns/tables?

Comment: I think I solved it, I created measure1: CALCULATE([Revenue],DATESYTD(dateadd('Date'[Date],-1,Year),"5/31"),ALLSELECTED(ClientType))
and then created another measure and did  CALCULATE([Measure1],all(ClientType[FilterToIgnore]))